# Simulating tail function in tkinter without freezing gui

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, tail

Basically I am trying to implement the tail function from ubuntu into a python tkinter button. The tail code works fine but only when I try to implement it into tkinter I am running into the problem of the entire gui freezing. There are several approaches I can take to fix this problem however I am wondering what would be the easiest and fastest way to approach this. Here is my code so far:

```
#gui code

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from subprocess import Popen 
import tkinter
import os
import time

master = Tk()
root = tkinter.Tk()

root.attributes("-topmost",True)
master.withdraw()
root.lift()

def userpass():
    os.startfile('config.ini')


def follow(thefile):
    thefile.seek(0,2)      # Go to the end of the file
    while True:
         line = thefile.readline()
         if not line:
             time.sleep(1)    # Sleep briefly
             continue
         yield line

def crap(tex):
    loglines = follow(open("jessica.gw2.log"))
    for line in loglines:
        #print(line)
        tex.insert(tkinter.END, line)
        tex.see(tkinter.END)


def cbc(tex):
    return lambda : crap(tex)

x = (root.winfo_screenwidth() - root.winfo_reqwidth()) / 1.1    
y = (root.winfo_screenheight() - root.winfo_reqheight()) / 20
root.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
tex = tkinter.Text(root)
tex.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)

b = Button(root, text="Set your Options ", command=userpass)
o = Button(root, text="Press to view logs", command = cbc(tex))
b.pack()
o.pack()


mainloop()
```

Comment: Try using `after` in `follow` function instead of `while True` loop.

Comment: @tobias_k tried that, didnt seem to work out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed around my function. Only had to make some slight modifications. I got rid of crap, cbc and the follow functions and then I changed this button

```
o = Button(root, text="Start monitoring Log file", command = viewlogfile)
```

so that it calls this function that I added

```
def viewlogfile():
    f = open('insertfilenamehere', "r")
    text = f.read()
    tex.insert(tkinter.END, text)
    tex.see(tkinter.END)
    root.after(3000,viewlogfile)
```

and then left everything else the same